# Multiple Parameters in a single Parameter (functions) in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters, bit-manipulation

Ok this might sound a little vague from the title, but that's because I have no idea how to word it differently. I'll try to explain what I mean: very often in certain libraries, the 'init' function accepts some parameters, but that parameter then accepts multiple parameters (right..). An example, would be like this:

apiHeader.h

```
#define API_FULLSCREEN   0x10003003
#define API_NO_DELAY     0x10003004
#define API_BLAH_BLAH    0x10003005
```

main.c:

```
apiInit(0, 10, 10, 2, API_FULLSCREEN | API_NO_DELAY | API_BLAH_BLAH);
```

How does this work? I can't find the answer anywhere, most likely because I don't know how it's actually called so I have no clue what to search for. It would be very useful in my current project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you wrote it, it **won't** work, because your flags are not setting different bits.

Comment: This is I realise, it was mostly for example purposes. Forgive me, I haven't slept in 30 hours now! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fifth parameter is usually a mask. It works by defining several consts (probably an `enum`) with values that are powers of two, or combinations of them. Then they are encoded into a single value using `|`, and decoded using `&`. Example:

```
#define COLOUR_RED   0x01
#define COLOUR_GREEN 0x02
#define COLOUR_BLUE  0x04
#define COLOUR_CYAN  (COLOUR_BLUE | COLOUR_GREEN) // 0x06

// Encoding
SetColour(COLOUR_RED | COLOUR_BLUE); // Parameter is 0x05

// Decoding
void SetColour(int colour)
{
  if (colour & COLOUR_RED) // If the mask contains COLOUR_RED
    // Do whatever
  if (colour & COLOUR_BLUE) // If the mask contains COLOUR_BLUE
    // Do whatever
  // ..
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you so much, I kinda _figured_ it was something like this, but I couldn't find an example in any source code I browsed!

Answer (score 9):

The parameter is usually called "$FOO flags" and the values are `or`-ed. The point is that the parameter is a numeric type that is constructed as the bitwise `or` of multiple possible values.

In the processing functions, the values are usually tested with a bitwise `and`:

```
if ( (flags & API_FULLSCREEN) != 0 )
```

You have to be careful to assign values in a way that keeps the OR operation linear. In other words, don't set the same bit in two different `or`-able values, like you did in your header. For example,

```
#define API_FULLSCREEN   0x1
#define API_NO_DELAY     0x2
#define API_BLAH_BLAH    0x4
```

works and allows you to deconstruct all combinations of flags in your function, but

```
#define API_FULLSCREEN   0x1
#define API_NO_DELAY     0x2
#define API_BLAH_BLAH    0x3
```

does not because `API_FULLSCREEN | API_NO_DELAY == API_BLAH_BLAH`.

Viewing from a higher level, a flags int is a poor man's variable argument list. If you consider C++, you should encapsulate such detail in a class or at least a `std::bitset`.

Comment: I preferably work in C, so I guess this is the way I'll have to look in to for now. However, I'll have a peek at std::bitset, as it's good to know such stuff I would assume.

Your answer was most enlightening, thank you!

Comment: I decided to mark the other question as answer, as it provided a more tangible example. Really I want to mark both answers though, so I just wanted to thank you again. :)

Comment: Your bitwise `and` example is incorrect. Operator precedence means you need parentheses to get the intended result: `if ( (flags & API_FULLSCREEN) != 0 )`.

Answer (score 1):

What they are doing there is using binary `OR` to combine the flags together.

so what is actually happening is:

`0x10003003 | 0x10003004 | 0x10003005 == 0x10003007`

It's still one parameter, but the 3 flags will combine to create a unique value for that parameter which can be used in the function.

Comment: I figured it'd be something like that, but several things come to my mind. For example, what if the result of two flags would be the same? Could you perhaps give a quick-n-dirty practical example of how this works? Would I have to go calculate -every- possibility first and then do a switch (flags) { /* cases go here */ }

Comment: @JesseBrands The programmer would have to make sure that there are no identical values themselves. So yes you would have to do a switch with the precomputed flag values.

Comment: @JesseBrands: The flags must be orthogonal of course. For a bit vector this means, each flag sets exactly one specific bit (and maybe some nonorthogonal mask bit to indicate that one of a group of flags has been used at all).

Answer (score 1):

What you are defining as multiple parameter is strictly a single parameter from the function signature point of view.
As for handling multiple `Options` based on a single parameter, as you can see there is the `bitwise Or Operator` which sets a single value for the parameter value. The body of the function then uses individual bits to determine the complete settings.

Usually, one bit is allocated for one option and they usually have two state(true/false) values.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is usually called "flags" and contains an or-ed combination of a set of allowed values.

```
int flags = API_FULLSCREEN | API_NO_DELAY;
```

The function can the take this integer parameter and extract the individual items like this:

```
int fullscreen_set = flags & API_FULLSCREEN;
int no_delay_set   = flags & API_NO_DELAY;
int blah_blah_set  = flags & API_BLAH_BLAH;
```

For this to work one has to be carfull in how one chooses the numeric values for the API_* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**Bitwise OR**

Bitwise OR works almost exactly the same way as bitwise AND. The only difference is that only one of the two bits needs to be a 1 for that position's bit in the result to be 1. (If both bits are a 1, the result will also have a 1 in that position.) The symbol is a pipe: |. Again, this is similar to boolean logical operator, which is ||.

01001000 | 10111000 = 11111000

and consequently 
72 | 184 = 248

So In you Method not a multiple parameter it is actully one parameter.
you can use Bitwise OR opearation on API_FULLSCREEN | API_NO_DELAY | API_BLAH_BLAH and passed it in method.

Answer (score 0):

The example that you gave will not work as expected. What you do is to use a particular bit for a particular option - and the OR combines then

**Example**

```
#define OPT1 1
#define OPT2 2
#define OPT3 4
```

So bit 1 is for OPT1, bit 2 is for OPT2 etc.

So `OPT1 | OPT3` sets bit 1 and 3 and gives a value of 5

In the function you can test if a particular option is required using the *AND* operator

So

```
void perform(int opts)
{
if (opts & OPT1)
{
 // Do stuff for OPT1
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of these parameters are defined in a way that they don't have any overlap. Something like this:

```
#define A 0x01
#define B 0x02
#define C 0x04
#define D 0x08
```

Given the above definitions, your can always determine which of the above variables have been `OR`ed using the bitwise `AND` operator:

```
void foo(int param)
{
    if(param & A)
    {
         // then you know that A has been included in the param
    }
    if(param & B)
    {
         // then you know that B has been included in the param
    }
    ...     
}

int main()
{
    foo (A | C);
    return 0;
}
```